# What does it mean to take the maximum over all POVMs?

Tags: measurement, information-theory, povm

What does it mean to take the maximum over all POVMs (in the definition of accessible information for example) ? The set of POVMs is infinite, how can we be sure that the maximum is attained by one of the elements ?

Comment: It potentially depends on the quantity you maximize. But most of the time, a compactness argument will do. Otherwise, when you see "maximum" think "supremum".

Comment: For intuition, note that there are infinitely many points in the interval $[0,1]$ but any continuous function defined over this set will attain its maximum for some real value in that interval according to the extreme value theorem.

Comment: @rnva Of course, it is a bit more subtle than that, because the most general POVM is an operator-valued measure, that is, there could be infinitely many POVM operators. So depending on the setting, it might well be that the maximum is *not* attained.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, what would be the compactness argument like for accessible information defined as $max_{POVM} I(X:Y)$ ? I have seen paper where authors go from a maximum over POVMs to a maximum over elements of a POVM indexed by some finite indices, and say that the continuous optimization problem became discrete optimization. Is the compactness arguments enough to say that ?

Comment: @yosh No. Compactness is used to show that the maximum is acquired on the set over which you optimize (i.e. no "sup" necessary) -- basically a continuous function on a compact set takes its maximum/supremum on the set. -- What you mention sounds more like an argument based on Caratheodory's Theorem, which limits how many points on the boundary you need to take to decompose elements of a convex set.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Could you please elaborate more on this Caratheodory's Theorem and how it allows to show that the maximum over all POVMs is the maximum over one POVM with finite elements ?